# Turn value into singular row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Current

```
Name   Quantity
---------------
Stella       2
Jennifer     2
Greg         3
```

Requested result

```
Name    Quantity 
---------------
Stella       1
Stella       1
Jennifer     1
Jennifer     1
Greg         1
Greg         1 
Greg         1
```

How should I do it?

```
declare @T table  
(  
  Name varchar(50),  
  Sales int  
)  
insert into @T values  
('Stella',   '2'),  
('Jennifer', '2'), 
('Greg',     '3')
```

Comment: SQL plays nicest with relational data. Your result is not a relation because it contains duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursion and borrowing Michael Fredrickson's setup code:

```
declare @T table (  
  Name varchar(50),  
  Sales int  
)

insert into @T values ('Stella',   '2')  
insert into @T values ('Jennifer', '2') 
insert into @T values ('Greg',     '3')

-- Recursive verion
;with People (Name, Sales) as
(
    select Name, Sales
    from @T
    union all
    select Name, Sales - 1
    from People
    where Sales - 1 > 0
)
select Name, 1 as Quantity
from People
option (maxrecursion 0) -- Recurse without limit
```

This seems to run faster on my box (5x faster than Michael Fredrickson's according to query plan, but with many more logical reads), not that it matters much.

Answer (score 4):

If the maximum value in the `quantity` column is known to be less than 32,767, you can use `Recursion` to generate numbers and join the Numbers to achieve your result.

```
/*******************************************
  Max Recursion Count in SQL Server is 32767
  Limitation of 32767 Numbers!
 ******************************************/
;WITH Numbers (Number) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + Number FROM Numbers WHERE Number < 100
)
SELECT  m.Name,
        Quantity = 1
  FROM  MyTable m 
        JOIN @numbers n ON m.Quantity <= n.Number
OPTION (MAXRECURSION  32767);
```

Comment: You can go over 100. See MAXRECURSION [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: You can also use MAXRECURSION 0 to go to infinity.  :)

Comment: @TimLehner: Good to know. May be the user can limit Max Recursion per his needs :)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: Not required as the CTE defined the Column name in the definition!

Comment: Returns error on my system (sql server express 2008 R2): "No column name was specified for column 1 of 'Numbers'."

Comment: works without an error on mine (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64))

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to have a pre-populated numbers table to do this:

```
declare @T table (  
  Name varchar(50),  
  Sales int  
)  

declare @numbers table (
  Number int
)

insert into @numbers values (1)
insert into @numbers values (2)
insert into @numbers values (3)
insert into @numbers values (4)
-- Etc... up to however many numbers is the max possible value for sales...

insert into @T values ('Stella',   '2')  
insert into @T values ('Jennifer', '2') 
insert into @T values ('Greg',     '3')

SELECT
    t.Name,
    1 AS Sales
FROM
    @T t JOIN
    @numbers n ON
        t.Sales >= n.Number
ORDER BY t.Name
```

That's how you could do it, but I'm not sure on *why* you would want to do it.